# how to use first processor input/output in last processor of flow in apache NIFI without storing files/DB

Tags: bash, caching, apache-nifi

I have 5 processors
**processor1**( `have a value`)=>**processor2**( `have b value`) => **processor3**(`calculate c=a+b`)=>**processor4**( `calculate d=c*a`)=>**processor5**( `calculate e=d*b`).
I'm going to use processor1 value in processor4 and processor2 value in processor5.
I need to store in cache processor1 input/output result to use in processor n. How can I achieve this please suggest if any processors are there or can I achieve this through bash script?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

for me it sounds like a sequence of UpdateAttribute processors:

```
UpdateAttribute(a=1, b=2) -> 
UpdateAttribute(c=a + b)  ->
UpdateAttribute(d=a * c)  ->
```

all 4 values you'll have as attributes of the same flow file

Comment: but values will change dynamically and we can't use` n UpdateAttribute processors`, Is there any script reference please suggest

Comment: There is nifi expression language that you could use in updateattributes or in any other processor/property where you see 'supports expression language' in documentation. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#plus